# Role-playing and being "stuck" with an archetype?

Tags: character-creation, dungeons-and-dragons, player-characters

I never played the "board" D&D games; my experience is limited to what is available via "classic" PC games. But I'd like to try D&D with the real players in real life at the board with the real DM holding a session (obviously - because it has to be so much better, right?)

Now the problem of why I didn't try yet is - in all of my play-through in different games and different times I always was leaning towards one archetype of a character. I don't want to discuss what exactly is that archetype, but I think it is something which will limit my freedom and overall game experience when applied to a real session.

How to deal with it? How to not fall into the same archetype when creating character again and again? To clarify my concerns:

- I've read here (on this site) that death is common and it has consequences. Cool concept, I'm all for it. But then I will create another character... of the same archetype and likely the same attributes/backstory elements. I assume it won't be great and people will object.
- DM may object to my chosen archetype. I don't have the reason "why" - it's not like it's a disruptive/abusive type of character in any way, but if the DM decides to object - I'm sort of "out of game" then. And I understand that DM is in the power to object and I'm fine with it.

*Further note: I've read the "[my guy](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/37103/what-is-my-guy-syndrome-and-how-do-i-handle-it/#37105)" syndrome and I believe it not to be the case as it's only about the choices I made when defining my character, not playing it. I might by wrong though.*

*I also have no idea how to properly tag this question - so if you can correct me, it would be great.*

Comment: Hi Alma, and welcome to RPG.stackexchange! I think this question might need some editing to conform to our standards, but many of us will be glad to help you. If it turns out we can't answer it here, you can always pop by in [chat] for more free-form discussion about your experiences. Cheers!

Comment: @kviiri well if there are some specific standards I need to meet apart from the general SE ones - happy to do it, please point me to those

Comment: Yeah, I don't really see any problem with this?

Comment: Some people are liable to interpret it as possibly being too broad or unclear, but I think it's fine.

Comment: I think that other answers to this question may hinge on *exactly* what you *don't* want to show: the archetype you like. Typically, in real life gamers tend to be pretty accepting folk (given the hobby, that should come as no surprise!), so always playing an elf fighter or whatever is no big deal, but gamers are still human, so it may annoy folks if a player's always playing a brazen Lothario, hateful racist, or long-winded-constantly-proselytizing-for-monotheism-in-a-pantheistic-world outcast or whatever. In short, I think answers do kind of need to *know* your fear to *address* your fear.

Comment: @HeyICanChan it's not like I have something to hide here but I just thought that the specifics about the archetype are irrelevant to the general case. No?

Comment: Honestly, the site doesn't care about general cases; the site cares about *your* problem. If answers to *your* case go wide and help others who have similar issues, that's on the answer not on you. The site wants to help *you* with *your* actual problem. If that problem is *I'm afraid of being judged by an in-real-life gaming group for my preference of playing elf fighters; should I be?* then that's totally a question experienced gamers can answer!

Comment: Do you have the Player's Handbook (PHB)? If your only experience is with PC MMOs I think you are going to find that you have MANY MANY more options for character customization while playing D&D. I would suggest building a few characters and see if you still feel the same way. You might end up alleviating your own fears and answering your own question.

Comment: @Newbie12345 those weren't "MMO"s but rather games which were actually following some edition of D&D and I created characters there (i.e. using the default rules implying class, background, skills and feats specifications)

Comment: it may be easier to answer with what edition of dnd your playing specificaly

Comment: @rpgstar as it's on hold now, I think I won't edit it - but I got what I needed regardless so I guess it's not necessary anymore :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Randomly generate a new backstory.

When I DM, I randomly generate NPCs quickly using dice and lists of character options and personality attributes. You can do the same when making a player character.

The exact tables are going to vary depending on which edition of D&D you're playing, but the general idea is e.g. roll 1d8 if your system has eight character classes.

To choose a personality trait, I find a convenient table to be [Pokémon's list of Natures](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Nature#List_of_Natures).

You might also use an online random character generator or NPC generator, such as the [Donjon random NPC generator](https://donjon.bin.sh/fantasy/random/#type=npc)

Another method is to ask each player at the table to come up with a new character concept for you, and then you choose whichever one you like best, or choose one at random by rolling dice.

Comment: The trait "list" is exceptionally cool, I didn't know it!

Comment: In 5e there's also a "background" system that gives a lot of the same kind of detail. These have similar tables for flaws, bonds, etc.